# django reverse url erro

Tags: python, django

I have following code in urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
     path('estimate_insert/',views.estimate_ui,name='estimate_i'),
     path('<int:id>/',views.estimate_ui,name='estimate_u'),
     path('estimate_delete/<int:id>/',views.estimate_d,name='estimate_d'),
     path('estimate_preview/<int:id>/',views.estimate_preview,name='estimate_v'),
]
```

I am matching these urls to the following code in views.py

```
def estimate_ui(request,id=0):
    if request.method=="GET":
        if id==0:
            form=EstimateForm()
        else:
            obj_estimate=Estimate.objects.get(pk=id)
            form=EstimateForm(instance=obj_estimate)
        return render(request,"Invoices/estimate_ui.html",{'form':form})
    
    else: 
        if id==0:
          form=EstimateForm(request.POST)
        else: 
          obj_estimate=Estimate.objects.get(pk=id)
          form=EstimateForm(request.POST,instance=obj_estimate)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
        return redirect('/invoices/')
```

the below mentioned url is causing problem when I access it.

```
path('<int:id>/',views.estimate_ui,name='estimate_u'),
```

When  I access I get the following error

```
NoReverseMatch at /invoices/status/3/
Reverse for 'estimate_u' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['estimate/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/invoices/status/3/
Django Version:
3.1.4
Exception Type:
NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'estimate_u' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['estimate/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

can anyone explain why is this happening.  I am accessing **`index.html--> linked to move to status.html(it has link to move estimate.html)--> at estimate.html`** I have many steps its basically a workflow based application. I watched almost all url related videos at youtube, searched google but found nothing that could help. thanks

Comment: Could you show your template? Place where you are trying to     open this url

Comment: Thanks man , I got it seriously, a very little  issue  I was accessing pk of the object with wrong instance.

Comment: Thats the typical error message that you get when you use {% url 'xyz' value %} and value is empty.

Comment: Amazing totally agreed, it was same issue,fixed thanks to ImustAdmit, Razenstein. Appreciate your contributions